Vary Geometry Node Instance Rotation Along Source Normal
I am new to the geometry nodes.
I am using this simple graph to put tiles on a plane to make easy roofs.
My problem is that when the curvature of the plane changes, the graph is no longer useful, if the roof is flat then it is okay, but if it has a slope change like chinese roofs then all breaks down.
I need a way to tell the instances to vary their angle according to the normals of the source plane and I can't seem to make it work.

Here is the file

HELP! Aaaand thanks in advance :D


I am not answering your question but I hope you'll have fun with this one:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/Ly03EWw4/

That is the standard way to rotate instances. Perhaps the normal-based rotation is not quite right?
For a comparative example, I replaced your "Align Euler to Vector" node's
    Y alignment about Z
to instead perform
    Z alignment around X (and then a corrective offset constant rotation)
This change brought all tiles from the same angle, as seen in this orthographic view:

to "lying down" against the roof at angles varying with the source normal. With apologies at not quite understanding the file's overall flow, I then just applied a constant rotation to roughly match the original look. Here's the same ortho view, but showing the tiles' angles vary down the roof's changing slope:

There's some clipping and other issues, but I hope this tweak may nudge it in the right direction.

Hey Joel! It looks good, however I cant seem to find the nodes you are using, maybe I am dumb or I just dont know enough about geometry nodes, but "rotate rotation" and "menu switch" I can't seem to dind them. Maybe you could share the scene if it is not much of a trouble?

@DanielGimenez Sorry! In v4, the apparently new and improved Rotate Rotation node took over for the still quite capable Rotate Euler node. If the Align Euler to Vector gets a roof's tiles following the normals, but with a uniform incorrect rotation, look for and try a Rotate Euler.

@DanielGimenez OH, and you don't need a second Align Euler to Vector node (just change the one you have), plus you don't need the Menu Switch at all (I just used it to take the screenshots). I've fixed the screenshots to show a working node arrangement (except for Rotate Euler being v4's Rotate Rotation).
